# How to get metrics about how times user enter to what controller in Yii2

Tags: yii2

How I can get metrics about how times user enter to what controller.
I have a system in Yii2, and I need know how many times the user enter to what controller. There is extensión for it? Some idea?

Comment: you can create a `BaseController` that extends the `yii\web\Controller` and add a `beforeAction()` in which you will write the logic for capturing the user and the target `action` or `controller`, and then extend all your controllers from the `BaseController`, you should add some more description along with efforts you have done so far , where is your code? you need to add it here and then you will get a proper answer.

Comment: search for audit extension  .. take a look at yii site for this  ..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple behavior to commit a necessary data. This behavior will handle an event of before action and put metrics into your storage, for example:

```
namespace app\behavior;

use yii\base\Behavior;
use yii\base\Application;
use yii\base\ActionEvent;

class ActionMetric extends Behavior
{

    public function events()
    {
        return [
            Application::EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION => 'run'
        ];
    }

    public function run(ActionEvent $event)
    {
        $actionId = $event->action->id;
        $controllerId = $event->action->controller->id;
        $userId = Yii::$app->user->id;
        //Here you will implement the metric saving into your storage
    }
}
```

Also you must attach this behavior to your application, for example in a config file

```
[
    'as behaviorName' => [
         'class' => 'app\behavior\ActionMetric';
    ], 
]
```